# How to create multiple filters within same function in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I've written some code with help to a previously answered question. Initially I had this code:

```
getT <- function(df, ID, Number){
  df %>%
    group_by(ID, Number) %>% 
    mutate( Distance = finish - begin) %>% 
    select(-begin,-finish,-symbols) %>%
    nest() %>% 
    mutate( data = map( data, ~ filter(.x, Distance == max(Distance)))) %>% 
    unnest()
}

getallT <- as.data.frame(getT(df))

getTID <- function(df, ID) {
  subset(x = getallT, subset = (ID))
}
```

Which gave this output:

```
ID     Number     Time     Distance
33         1      2.00         870
33         2      1.98         859
33         3      0.82         305
33         4      2.02         651
33         5      2.53         502
```

I wanted to filter it by `Time` so I used this code(thanks to a post below):

```
getHLN <- function(df, ID) {
  getallT %>% filter (ID ==id & !between(Time, 1.50, 2.10))
}
```

Which now gives this output:

```
  ID Number Time Distance
1 33      3 0.82      305
2 33      4 2.02      651
3 33      5 2.53      502
```

But now I've come across an issue so now I'm left wondering how to either:
A. Filter out Number 4 & 5 so that I can create a separate function with a different `Time` filter for it. To later create another different function to merge the two previous functions into one.
OR
B. Create a different `Time` filter specifically for Number 4 & 5 within the same function.

I tried doing A. by using `filter (getallT, Number >= 3) %>%` but doesn't work. I would rather go with B though if possible. So something like...
For ID numbers 1-3: filter(!between(Time,1,2))
For ID numbers 4-5: filter(!between(Time 1.5,2.3)) within the same function.
I've been trying out a few things for the past day but keep getting error messages such as `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types.`

I've been trying out what's on here but must not be doing something write so need some insight!
http://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/dplyr_tutorial.html

Here is an example dataset

```
df <- data.frame(ID=rep(33,5),
                 Number=1:5,
                 Time=c(2.00,1.98,0.82,2.02,2.53),
                 Distance=c(870,859,305,651,502))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a small reproducible example

Comment: Please get into the habit as you ask SO questions of including a reproducible dataset. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I do have the bad habit of forgetting to add that! Woops, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is somewhat confusing:

```
getHLN <- function(df, ID) {
  data_df1 <- getT(race_df)
  subset(x = getallT, subset = (ID)) %>%
    filter (!between(Time, 1.50, 2.10))
}
```

Mainly because it takes a `df` argument, which it doesn't within, and uses  two data.frames from the outer environment in `race_df` and `getallT`. Your calls to `subset` are also a tad mystifying. As it stands, the function will return whatever the expression beginning with `subset` will return, and will throw away `data_df1`.

```
getHLN <- function(df, ID) {
  # this gets locally assigned within the function and then 
  # becomes unreachable once the function ends
  data_df1 <- getT(df)
  # this expression would produce the last value of the function
  # and so the function would return its value
  subset(x = getallT, subset = (ID)) %>%
    filter (!between(Time, 1.50, 2.10))
}
```

We can do the sort of filtering you described by creating `ID %in% ... & !between()` logic for both sets of criteria you described, wrapping each in parentheses so that they're evaluated as "and" logic, and then adding both to the `filter` function and joining them with the `|` operator ("or"), which `filter` will then evaluate as "filter df where (criteria a AND B) OR (criteria c AND d)".

```
getHLN <- function(df) {
  df %>% filter(
    (Number %in% 1:3 & !between(Time, 1, 2)) |
      (Number %in% 4:5 & !between(Time, 1.50, 2.10))
    )
}
```

Comment: While fiddling about further I realised my data_df1 is pointless but now you showed me an even sleeker code so for that I thank you. I am self-taught in R and new to programming in general too. I'm sure you can tell. Is there a way I can add another `filter` related to `Time` for just `Number` 4 and 5 though? I keep getting the same error message returned.

Comment: Ah yes, I re-read your question and now see what you're hoping to do -- please see my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! My code looks better and is functional now!